# How to make an object resident to a function call?

Tags: php, object, stdclass

I have a PHP program I'm writing that does a SOAP request, and it returns an Object. I need to write a function where it takes the data from this Object and uses it in various ways, but I don't want it to do a SOAP request each time if the SOAP request for the data in this Object is already resident.

Pseudo-code example:

```
$price = GetPartPrice("1234");


function GetPartPrice($part_number) {

If Parts_List_Object not found then do SOAP request to get Parts_List_Object. 

}
```

The problem I see is that I don't know where or how to store if the Parts_List_Object is already there. Do I need to set something up to make the StdClass object that gets requested from the SOAP/JSON request global or is there a better method to do all this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to build a registry of these objects where you store the ones you fetch and look up the ones you need.  That allows you to simply grab a reference to the instance that you've already loaded.  A very basic example:

```
class PartListRegistry {
    private static $list = array();

    // After you do the SOAP request, call this to save a reference to the object
    public static function addPartObject($key, $obj) {
        self::$list[$key] = $obj;
    }

    // Call this to see if the object exists already
    public static function getPartObject($key) {
        if (isset(self::$list[$key])) {
            return self::$list[$key];
        }
        return null;
    }
}

function GetPartPrice($part_number) {
    $part = PartListRegistry::getPartObject($part_number);
    if ($part === null) {
        $part = .... // Do your SOAP request here
        // Save a reference to the object when you're done
        PartListregistry::addPartObject($part_num, $part);
    }
    // Do your stuff with the part ....
}
```